# Best way to determine if an SCP transfer fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

At the end of a script if successful it creates a file (files) and stores it into a destination directory; I'm then retrieving the file (files) via scp from a server back to my workstation.  The user of the script has the ability to determine an output location for the file (or files) they are retrieving.

What would be the best way to determine if the file (files) were successfully transferred?  My main issue being if the user retrieves the file to a location like /home/$USERNAME/Desktop and there are files on the desktop.  What's the best way to determine if there is a new file on the desktop that was retrieved by means of the script?

In the end, I'm really just trying to determine if the transfer failed or not. When the script ends, I'd like to inform the user that the file was successfully transferred to the output directory.

Here are my thoughts...

```
if (ssh user@server "[ find /myFiles -maxdepth 0 -empty -exec return 0 \; ]")
then
    scp user@server:/myFiles localhost:/DirToSave 
fi
```

But this isn't working, however, I think using this method will simplify my other issues by just letting me know that the files I'm looking for aren't there anyway.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: One problem is that even if `/myFiles` isn't *empty* and doesn't execute the `-exec` primary, `find` will still exit with status code 0 unless an actual error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rsync.

```
rsync -arvz -e ssh user@server:/myFiles localhost:/DirToSave
```

This will tell you in the output if files have changed. You can run it multiple times cheaply

An error code will be returned if it fails. Can be tested with: 
`if [ $? -ne 0 ]`
This may be sensitive if files change while the code is writing or permissions can't be set, such as on timestamps.

Comment: Except don't test like that; just put the `rsync` call in the `if`.